# Streamlit: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I'am having the next ERROR in my streamlit app:

My ERROR is:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

My code is:

```
import streamlit as st

if st.button("SUBMIT"):

    calculation = 23*2

    string = "Hello"

    result= (calculation + str(string))

    st.success(result)
```

Comment: `calculation` is an integer. In python, you can't add an integer directly with a string. Use `str(calculation)` in its place

Comment: Read the error message again. You try to add an integer and a string. `calculation` is `46` and that's an integer. `str(string))` is a string (and I'm not sure why you're converting the string `"Hello"` to a string again). And if you ask "Why is there no automatic conversion" then answer the following question. What would you expect the result of `"1" + 2` to be and why?

Answer (score 1):

Edit from your example:

```
import streamlit as st

if st.button("SUBMIT"):
    calculation = 23*2
    string = "Hello"
    result = (str(calculation) + string)
    st.success(result)
```